# Add endpoints to a division using jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, object, connection, anchor, jsplumb

I am working with the jsPlumb library where I have a toolbox from which I need to drag and drop elements onto the container and then provide an option for the users to connect the dropped elements within the container.

I am currently able to drag and drop an element. But what I need to do here is to drop the element with the connectors/endpoints(anchors).

I have defined the connector properties as follows.

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {

    jsPlumb.setContainer($('#container'));

  //Connector Defaults
    var connectorProperties = {
            isTarget:true,
            isSource:true,
            maxConnections:-1,
            anchors:["Left","Right"],
            endpoint:["Dot",{
                radius:4
            }],
            connector:["Flowchart"],
            connectorStyle:{
                strokeStyle:"5c96bc",
                linewidth:1,
                outlineColor:"transparent",
                outlineWidth:4
            },
            paintStyle:{
                fillStyle:"transparent"
            },
            hoverPaintStyle: {
                fillStyle:"FF0000"
            }
    };
```

And once the first element is dropped, I have defined the connector properties over that dropped element.

```
drop: function (e, ui) {

    var mouseTop = e.clientY;
    var mouseLeft = e.clientX;

    var dropElem = ui.draggable.attr('class');
    droppedElement = ui.helper.clone();
    ui.helper.remove();
    $(droppedElement).removeAttr("class");
    $(droppedElement).draggable({containment: "container"});
    jsPlumb.repaint(ui.helper);


    //If the dropped Element is a TABLE then->
    if (dropElem == "stream ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle") {
        var newAgent = $('<div>');
        jsPlumb.addEndpoint(newAgent,connectorProperties);
        newAgent.attr('id', i).addClass('streamdrop');
        var elemType = "table";
        $("#container").addClass("disabledbutton");
        $("#toolbox").addClass("disabledbutton");

        $('#container').append(newAgent);
```

But am unable to view the connectors on the dropped element. Only the `streamdrop` div is dropped on the container and the container and the toolbox are disabled according the declared code that follows the connector addition code above.

[image]

Any suggestions on why I am unable to view the connectors/endpoints on the dropped element and how to resolve this error will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think u did lot of stuff which is not needed. Suggestion Use - jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(droppedElement),connectorProperties); 
Can you create a fiddle for better understanding.

> var newAgent = $('');
>           jsPlumb.addEndpoint(newAgent,connectorProperties);

Comment: Thanks for the response.